# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean by reading records from database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I've got readOne function. This function will read only one record from category table and assign values to name and description variables. It looks like this:

```
public function readOne($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = '.$id)->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->name = $result['name'];
    $this->description = $result['description'];
}
```

I'm trying to call it with using this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if ( isset( $_POST['read'], $_POST['id']) ) {

    $cat = new Category($conn);

    $id = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


    echo $cat->readOne($id);
}}
?>
<div>
<h3>readOne():</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Category id :</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Id"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="read" name="read"/><br />
</div>
```

but I get an error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean" in this line:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

EDIT: connection code:

```
<?php

class Database {

public function getConnection() {
    $result = false;
    try {
        $result = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo', 'root', '');
    } catch(PDOException $e) { }
    return $result;
}
}
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
if (!$conn) {
die("Error connecting to the database");
}

?>
```

Comment: @Anant using `isset()` with multiple arguments is fine. Also, `execute()` returns a boolean so you can't do what you suggest.

Comment: @MrCode you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query execution code need some changes like below:-

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = "'.$id.'"'); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$this->name = $result['name'];
```

**Use this code for your question what you asked currently after accepting answer (`But now when i'm clicking "read" button nothing happens?`):-**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if ( isset( $_POST['read'], $_POST['id']) ) {

    $cat = new Category($conn);

    $id = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


    $_SESSION['description'] =  $cat->readOne($id);
}}
?>
<div>
<h3>readOne():</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Category id :</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Id"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="read" name="read"/><br />
</div>
<div class= "description"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['description']) && !empty($_SESSION['description'])){ echo $_SESSION['description'];}?></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning `$stmt` with the return value of `execute()`. You need to replace the line `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = '.$id)->execute();` with:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = '.$id);
$stmt->execute();
```